# the object specified does not belong to a list

Tags: sharepoint-2007, master-pages, moss, sharepoint-designer

I am having a problem to visualize the `http://servername/SearchCenter/`, it is showing the message:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: the object specified does not belong to a list
```

and is showing the stack trace:

```
    [SPException: the object specified does not belong to a list.]
       Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetItem(String strUrl, Boolean bFile, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId) +578
.
.
.
```

And is throwing this exception only when I am logged in.
I already got the project done, somebody just told me it could be a masterpage problem.

Whenever I open the subsite in the sharepoint designer `SearchCenter` the page `SearchCenter/Pages/Default.aspx`
it redirects to the root solution and open the `_catalogs/Pages/searchmain.aspx`

The code in the `searchmain.aspx` have the header.

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral"
 meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>

<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SEARCHWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

The same error occurs when I create a `subsite`, when you click create, it outputs:

```
The object specified does not belong to a list.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetItem(String strUrl, Boolean bFile, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Item() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb.GetPageLayoutCollectionFromStringMustCloseFileWeb(String pageLayoutUrls, Char[] delimiters, SPSite site) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.InitializePublishingWebDefaults()
```

It also appears on the first page.

```
 ! The specific object doesn't belong to a list.
```